# Why does my printout have bottomless lines of characters?

Tags: troubleshooting, printing

I printed out some code from Visual Studio 2008 (12 pages), and a few lines of each page are printed only partially.  It's as if the bottom 80% of each of the characters were chopped off and left for dead.  I could only see the top part of each of the characters.  Except for these few lines per page, everything else looked fine.

It's not the toner cartridge, because I printed out a 91-page PDF from the same printer and the same computer, and nothing got dropped.

What would cause this?  Printer driver?  Network?  (It's a networked laser printer.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the last line of each page the bottom margin may be too small and the printer can't write there.

If it is in the middle of the page, maybe colored lines with a black printer?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The lines that do this can be anywhere on the page.  Also, sometimes single words in a chopped-off line will appear fine.  It is a color printer, but black-only words get chopped off.